# Separating large client library/sdk design pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am implementing a API sdk that has a huge number of operations and want to split it into more manageable classes by grouping certain operations.

One common way I found is something like this:

```
  public class TwitterTemplate extends AbstractOAuth1ApiBinding implements Twitter {

        private TimelineOperations timelineOperations;

        private UserOperations userOperations;

        private FriendOperations friendOperations;

        private ListOperations listOperations;

        private SearchOperations searchOperations;

        private DirectMessageOperations directMessageOperations;

        private BlockOperations blockOperations;
```

So I create an class for each group of operations and hold each group within a containing class

Is there a name for this pattern? And are there any obvious alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

RESTful looks the best choice for you, Split your Operations into resource Operations such as (Users, Friends,Messages, Blocks), Then using CRUD/Query on the Resource should cover all the Operations.